# Error when running insert using mongoose connected to mongo atlas

Tags: mongodb

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

When i tried invoking the controller function its throwing a timeout error.I shared my code which im using to make a connection to atlas and the code im using when /api/users/ route is accessed.

```
export const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: false,
      ssl: true,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

export const addUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const user = await User.create(req.body);
    return res.status(200).send({
      sucess: true,
      data: user,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(501).json({
      error: "Server error",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Are u getting the MongoDB connected console message before you run the controller?

Comment: Im receiving timeout error when i access that endpoint from postman